# Error php odbc conect to store procedure in sqlserver 2005

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, odbc

I tried 5 days ago about php odbc connection to store procedure in sqlsrever2005, but it not successful. i had problem in odbc_exec point.

I dont know why ?

My coding as the following:

```
$connection= odbc_connect("'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=.;DATABASE=test", "us1","1") or die("Fail");
$stmt= odbc_prepare($connection,"{CALL myproce1('2','','','','')}");
if(!$stmt) die("could not prepare statement ");
$data=odbc_execute($stmt,array());
if(!$data) die("Error exec");
```

Regards,

Comment: Use `if(!$data) die(odbc_errormsg());` instead of `if(!$data) die("Error exec");` and update question with real error.

Comment: odbc_exec() expects parameter 2 to be string

Comment: Try this: `odbc_execute($stmt,array("2"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For prepared statements you should probably attach some params.

```
$connection= odbc_connect("'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=.;DATABASE=test", "us1","1") or die("Fail: " . odbc_errormsg());
$stmt= odbc_prepare($connection,"{CALL myproce1(?,'','','','')}");
if(!$stmt) die("could not prepare statement:" . odbc_errormsg());
$data=odbc_execute($stmt,array("2"));
if(!$data) die('Execute fail.'); // execute error doesn't feed odbc_errormsg()
```